# How to test that a created value is unique?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

In my Java class I have a method that creates an object and implements certain logic to assign random values to some of its variables, using one static instance of Random (`static Random rn = new Random();`). One of these variables is `objectId`.

How can I write **Spock** unit test to verify that `objectId` value is **unique among all created objects**?

If I needed it just for **two consecutive objects** I would write something like this (omitting imports):

```
class MyTest extends Specification {

    def @Shared obj = new MyObject()

    def "consecutive IDs are not equal"() {
        given:
            def id1 = ar.randomObject(MyObject.rn).getId()
            def id2 = ar.randomObject(MyObject.rn).getId()
        expect:
            id1 != id2

    }
}
```

How to extend this logic to a variable number of instances?

Comment: You can't test it is always unique. using Random to generate ids isn't a good idea

Comment: Indeed, it's guaranteed that it isn't always unique for a big enough set of ids

Comment: @tim_yates  Right you are. That was actually the purpose of the test. I'm OK with 10,000 IDs and guaranteed to fail with 100,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?
Given a test class:

```
class Test {
    static Random r = new Random()
    Long objectId = r.nextLong()
}

//Test Case
def "consecutive IDs are not equal"() {
    given: "20 ids from 20 Test Objects"
        def ids = (1..20).collect { new Test().objectId }

    expect: "ids are unique"
        // use unique(false) not to mutate the list
        ids.unique(false) == ids
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've learned a lot just by deciphering your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid my groovy isn't up to the task, but the logic is:

```
def ids as Set

def "IDs are not duplicated"() {
  expect:
    ids.contains(id) == false

  cleanup:
    ids.add(id)

  where:
    id << listOfAllIds()
}
```

That is: assert that each id isn't currently known.  When the assertion doesn't fail, record the id as currently known.